# exponential inequality: $[r/(r-2)]^{1-2/r}\leq \exp\{2/r\}$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following hold:

$$\bigg(\frac{r}{r-2}\bigg)^{1-2/r}\leq\exp\bigg\{\frac{2}{r}\bigg\}, \ r>2?$$

How to show it?

I see that the maximum of $x^{1/x}$ occurs at $x=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\frac 2r = t > 1$, then your inequality is equivalent to:

$$\left(1 + \frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{1-t} = \left(\left(1+\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{\frac{1-t}{t}}\right)^t\leq e^t$$
because $\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x \leq  e$ for for any positive $x.$